# How can I cast c++ struct to Object?

Tags: .net, struct, c++-cli

How can I cast c++ struct to Object ?

```
struct FileInfo{
float width, height;
};

FileInfo *info = (FileInfo*)malloc(sizeof(FileInfo));
Object ^obj = (Object^)info;
```

error 'type cast' : cannot convert from FileInfo * to 'System::Object ^

**UPDATE** I need to transfer Object^ to the method. I can't modify the method. (it's api)

Comment: You can't. Your FileInfo struct has been allocated on the unmanaged heap and you are trying to cast it to a managed object on the managed heap.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1997935/516486

Comment: You can't cast directly. It is possible to refer to instances of `FileInfo` from .NET but the best way of doing that depends on what you intend to do with the `Object` you've created.