# How do I return a C++/CLI object to Java using JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I'm using C++/CLI to connect a Java client to my C# `ServiceHost`. So far I have used this to access my service, where `Client` defines my `ServiceHost` client:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Client_GetData(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring xml)
{
    try
    {
        Client ^client = gcnew Client();

        return env->NewStringUTF(marshal_as<string>(
              client->GetData(marshal_as<String^>(env->GetStringUTFChars(xml, 0))
        )).c_str());
    }
    catch(Exception^ ex)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(ex->ToString());
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

That works fine, but **I want to be able to store my `Client` object on the Java side** in order to make calls with the same object instead of opening and closing the connection for each call.

It has been difficult to find anything definitive about this. Is it possible?

#### Here is the solution I came up with per the marked answer:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Client_Create(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    try
    {
        Client^ client = gcnew Client();
        client->Connect();
        long result =  reinterpret_cast<long>(GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(client)).ToPointer());
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception^ ex)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(ex->ToString());
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

By storing that long in Java, I can pass it as a `jlong` parameter to my `GetData` method:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Client_GetData(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jlong ptr, jstring xml)
{
    try
    {
        GCHandle h = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr)));
        Client^ client = safe_cast<Client^>(h.Target);

        const char* xmlChars = (const char*)env->GetStringChars(xml, 0);
        string xmlString(xmlChars);
        env->ReleaseStringChars(xml, (const jchar*)xmlChars);

        const char* data = marshal_as<string>(client->GetData(
                marshal_as<String^>(xmlString)
            )).c_str();

        int length = strlen(data);

        return env->NewString((const jchar*)data, length);
    }
    catch(EndpointNotFoundException^)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    catch(Exception^ ex)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(ex->ToString());
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

All I have left to do is create another JNI method to close the `Client` connection and dispose the object.

Comment: If your data is not characters then you shouldn't use strings to transfer it. If it is then you should not convert it from UTF-16LE to something else (esp. non-Unicode or non-standard Unicode [JNI's *UTF functions]) and back to UTF-16LE. Both .NET and Java on Windows use UTF-16LE. Use JNI's `GetStringChars` and `NewString`, and `std::wstring` if needed as an intermediary (C++/CLI doesn't support `std::u16string`, which in VC++ is effectively the same thing).

Comment: @TomBlodget I appreciate your feedback. I edited your suggestion into my solution above, though I'm not sure if what I did is the best way to go about it. Please let me know if you see something else I should change. However, the XML I'm passing through this function is in UTF-8, so for the sake of knowledge- does your suggestion still apply in this case?

Comment: Both .NET and JVM store strings in counted sequences of UTF-16 codeunits and with the same endianness. Use `GetStringLength` to get the number of codeunits. `GetStringChars` gives you a pointer to the codeunits. Then call `Marshal::PtrToStringUni` with the pointer cast to an IntPtr and the number of codeunits to get a .NET string.

Comment: If your XML is in a JVM or .NET string, its encoding is UTF-16. If the xml declaration says otherwise, it's just wrong. If you store it an array of bytes, then it can have whatever encoding you desire, but the xml declaration should say what that is. XmlReader/XmlWriter and similar classes do this for you.

Comment: The XML is declared as UTF-8 and must be passed as a string,  unfortunately that part is out of my hands. Is there an advantage to using `Marshal::PtrToStringUni` over casting between char/jchar? That does seem cleaner, I'm just trying to get a better grasp of this. Thanks

Comment: `Marshal::PtrToStringUni(IntPtr,Int32)` is just the simplest way to copy the string data from pinned JVM memory straight into .NET managed memory allocated for the string. It uses the information available from JNI about the source string (location and count) and makes no restrictions on the content (termination, embedded NUL characters, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your native method to return a jlong, and return the address of the newly created Client object pointer.

Create a second native method for cleaning up memory, which accepts the store jlong from the previous call, cast it back to a Client pointer, and delete it.

See [This answer for the correct syntax on handle to pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997935/2824919)

Comment: You are correct sir. Thank you! I will edit my solution into my post.